# Query about JavaScript data type of function

Tags: javascript, types, typeof

At most places on Web, data types in JavaScript are mentioned as  -

- Boolean
- Null
- Undefined
- Number
- String
- Symbol
- Object

I have a query about data type of a function -

The typeof operator for a function declaration or definition returns "function". Then how come "Function" is not listed as a data type? Also, aren't functions Objects in JavaScript? Then how come typeof of function declaration or definition returns "function" and not "Object"?

Comment: Edited the question now and removed the part which seem duplicate from the question. Please remove the duplicate marker on the question.

Comment: The `typeof` operator returns "function" for function objects because the spec says so. See [MDN JavaScript Reference - `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). See also [MDN JavaScript Reference - Data Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types).